# How to count the number of lines of text displayed in a Cypress test

Tags: vuejs3, cypress

In Vuejs3 I wrote a `MoreOrLessTextButton` component that keeps the length of the text displayed within the amount of lines wanted.

The component takes some arguments, but these are the most important:

```js
<MoreOrLessTextButton :textToDisplay="testText" :numberOfLines="4" />
```

It attached a " *..more*" link at the end and if clicked it displays all the text with a " *(less)*" link at the end. It keeps the right amount of lines and text length on that line depending on the screen/window size of the user. Basically I wrote and extensive version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605049/1735311

Now I would like to test this in Cypress. I can only find ways to count the number of characters.

```
cy.get('[data-testid="MoreOrLessTextButton"]').invoke('text').then(
  (text) => {
    expect(text.length).to.be.at.most(300)
  })
```

This would force me to basically assess in JS the number of characters in one line to see if it works (it is a lot more complicated but it's an example). I am looking for something like:

```
cy.get('[data-testid="MoreOrLessTextButton"]').invoke('text').then(
  (text) => {
    expect(text.lines).to.match(4)
  })
```

Is there anything like this available?

**UPDATE**

@agoff requested the HTML output, and it looks something like this:

```
<span data-testid="MoreOrLessTextButton">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, constasipi sit amet, (......) consectetue.</span><a> (less)</a>
```

Comment: What does the HTML in the browser look like?

Comment: <span data-testid="MoreOrLessText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, constasipi sit amet, ...... consectetue.</span><a> (less)</a>

Comment: How do you get 4 lines from a span? Are you asking about wrapped text rather than actual lines?

Comment: If that's so, then you need to provide CSS, width of page, other elements that take up space - I can't see what you are actually testing.

Comment: @A.A.Qadosh this span its maximum width is decided by the screen/window size.  The text (if long enough) has limitless space to continue on the next line. 

I am limiting the lines of the text (using Vuejs) to a maximum number of lines. I do this by adding chars until the height of the span doubles. Multiply and I cut space for a ..more link and trim the last incomplete word. I implemented basically an advance version of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114496/1735311

Comment: @A.A.Qadosh sorry that is the wrong link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605049/1735311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CSS line count calculation for "single" line of text in a wrapping element

There are a lot of CSS factors to consider, but here is the basic calculation based on [line-height documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

You can of course substitute your own algorithm derived from [Find rendered line breaks with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604798/find-rendered-line-breaks-with-javascript/55605049#55605049), whatever that might be.

```js
function countLines($el) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle($el[0], null)
  const height = $el[0].offsetHeight 
  const fontSize = style.getPropertyValue('font-size').replace('px', '')
  const lines = Math.ceil(height / (fontSize*1.2))
  return lines
}

it('tests at viewport 100x660', () => {
  cy.visit('html/lines.html')
  cy.get('span')
    .then(countLines)
    .should('eq', 2)
})

it('tests at viewport 500x500', () => {
  cy.viewport(500,500)
  cy.visit('html/lines.html')
  cy.get('span')
    .then(countLines)
    .should('eq', 4)
})
```

[image]

Notes:

- assumes line-height is "normal" (1.2em)
- may vary by font
- padding and margins affect the calculation
- flexbox and grid layout affect it also if other elements squeeze the target element
- browser type (user agent) may also affect the calculation

Using this text in the example test:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis cum eveniet sed, autem corrupti repellendus error nihil provident adipisci incidunt, aspernatur velit recusandae alias molestias nobis, nam labore exercitationem cupiditate.

Comment: thank you men, this is atleast very different from my calculation so it is a good check. But I'm assuming there is no homegrown cypress way so I'll use yours. It's very neat thank you for the time.