# Accessing displayed hyphens of an HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

Given a

```html
<div
  lang="en"
  style="
    overflow-wrap: word-break;
    hyphens: auto;
    width: 8.6em;
    background-color: highlight;
    color: highlightText;
    font-size: 20px;
  ">
    This is a text that is long enough
    to cause a line break if set so.
    By using words like
    "incomprehensibilities",
    we can demonstrate word breaks.
</div>
```

I would like to access the formatted text with hyphenations with JavaScript to get a string similar to:

`"This is a text that is long enough to cause a line break if set so. By using words like "incomprehensibilit-ies", we can demon-strate word breaks."`.

N.B. hyphens in `incomprehensibilit-ies` and `demon-strate`.

Is this possible?

The use case is that I need a way to break and hyphenate text in a `<text>` element of an SVG by only using SVG elements.

Comment: use ``<tspan>``

Comment: To find the line breaks there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604798/find-rendered-line-breaks-with-javascript/55605049# but to tell you whether there is an hyphen or not seems to be a bit complicated since it's not part of the DOM at all. You could obviously add one every time a word is splitted but I'm not sure browsers add hyphens every time, and I'm not sure either if we can assume a particular width for the hyphen.

Comment: And just to confirm, with a `lang="en"` element, it won't add an hyphen to a Korean word for instance, even though it will break it. So we'd need some kind of dictionary I guess, or to tap in the browser's heuristics directly...

Comment: Interesting question. One OT out of curiosity: would replacing SVG text/tspan elements in your target SVG with "raw" styled HTML inside SVG `foreignObject` fit in your use-case? (From a quick test it should work.)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

[image]

Also read: https://www.brucebrotherton.com/blog/hyphens-on-the-web/

---

It is the browser in charge of rendering text, you have to analyze where text is rendered. With Canvas or SPAN

Far from perfect. This one:

- wraps each word in a `<span>`
- calculates by `offsetHeight` if a SPAN spans multiple lines
- of so it found a hyphened word
- it then **removes** each *last* character from the `<span>`
  to find when the word wrapped to a new line

[image]

The *Far from perfect* is the word "demonstrate" which ***"fits"*** when shortened to "demonstr" **-** "ate" But is not the English spelling

[image]

Needs some more JS voodoo

```html
<style>
  .hyphen { background: pink }
  .remainder { background: lightblue }
</style>

<process-text lang="en" style="display:inline-block;
         overflow-wrap: word-break; hyphens: auto; zoom:1.2; width: 7em">
  By using words like
  "incomprehensibilities",
  we can demonstrate word breaks.
</process-text>

<script>
  customElements.define('process-text', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let words = this.innerHTML.trim().split(/(\W+)/);
        let spanned = words.map(w => `<span>${w}</span>`).join('');
        this.innerHTML = spanned;
        let spans = [...this.querySelectorAll("span")];
        let defaultHeight = spans[0].offsetHeight;
        let hyphend = spans.map(span => {
          let hyphen = span.offsetHeight > defaultHeight;
          console.assert(span.offsetHeight == defaultHeight, span.innerText, span.offsetWidth);
          span.classList.toggle("hyphen", hyphen);
          if (hyphen) {
            let saved = span.innerText;
            while (span.innerText && span.offsetHeight > defaultHeight) {
              span.innerText = span.innerText.slice(0, -1);
            }
            let remainder = document.createElement("span");
            remainder.innerText = saved.replace(span.innerText, "");
            remainder.classList.add("remainder");
            span.after(remainder);
          }
        })
        console.log(this.querySelectorAll("span").length, "<SPAN> created" );
      }) //setTimeout to read innerHTML
    } // connectedCallback
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider turning the problem around from "find out where the browser inserted line breaks" to "tell the browser to make specific line breaks".

This can be easily achieved by inserting [soft hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) (`&shy;`) at desired locations.